# Authentication & logins - Bootstrap - Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, authentication

This is mostly regarding security but also regarding advice on the best method:

I originally designed a website that would load a new html/php file for each tab but have recently changed to using bootstrap and using the nav-tabs so that I don't have tons of html files and also to make the website run a bit smoother.

Currently using method 1...

Method 1 - Login on the html page and use a php file to authenticate a user and check the database for the correct credentials, set session as either admin/customer/staff etc and redirects to the desired page as shown below.

```
if ($row[0]=='1') // admin login
{
    $_SESSION['auth']='Admin';
    //redirect to admin page
}
else if ($row[0]=='2') // business login
{
    $_SESSION['auth']='Staff';
    //redirect to staff page
}
```

Method 2 - Is there a way to use JQuery (or some other method) of hiding tab content unless the session is set to admin/customer/staff etc? If possible, is this secure?
In other words, use the login form to run the php file to check for user credentials in the database and request the user authentication level (admin, staff etc) and redirect back to the index page, but to open the admin/staff tab content? something similar to this for the authentication:

```
if (@$_SESSION['auth'] == "Admin")
{
    header('Location: https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html#admin');
}
else if (@$_SESSION['auth'] == "Staff")
{
    header('Location: https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html#staff');
}
else
{
    //deny access and revert to login screen
}
```

What I am asking for the above code is, is this how to redirect to my homepage but to load tabcontent by using #staff/#admin? Then is it possible to do something like below?

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="staff">
//Some code either goes here to only allow access if the session is set to staff
//Alternatively if code doesnt go here, is it possible to use JQuery to target this tabpanel to show this tab if user authentication is staff
</div>
```

Method 3 - I find this hard to believe, but I have been told that setting up the tab as normal and opening the tab after a successful login attempt is secure. Is this true? If so, I know I can use AJAX to do a live login and simply direct the login to the staff/admin tab content

So in a quick summary to make sure I've explained as best I can, is method 1,2 or 3 best for performance and security.

Does

```
header('Location: https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html#admin');
```

open the website at the admin tab content.

Thank you in Advance from someone a little unsure on the best practices to use.

Comment: Using JavaScript/jQuery is probably not secure, anyone can see & change the entire script in most browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security you definitely want to do server side validation. Your PHP should NEVER render any HTML that the user shouldn't see.

Therefore your index.html should also be index.php.

```
header('Location: https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php');
```

And then in this file you repeat the `$_SESSION['auth']` check.

```
if (@$_SESSION['auth'] == "Admin")
{
    // Render admin tab
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Eliott, but just to make sure I fully understand... I should do my login as I have suggested in method 1 and stay away from AJAX for the actual login?

Comment: Yes, you should never render content to the browser before they are authenticated. Otherwise someone can just view the page source and bypass it.

Comment: On that same note Eliott, is it still safe to produce content from a database without authentication (I am creating a small content management system within this website and need to display content from the database and currently display text and populate tables from a database to all visitors)?

Comment: Yeah showing content to the users from the database is fine. You just never want to send any privileged information to unprivileged users :)

Comment: Much appreciated for that advice Eliott! Any chance you would know of any good books or reading material to gain more knowledge specifically on security for web development?

Comment: I'm afraid not. But one important thing is never to try and invent new security models. Experts spend years on this sort of thing, it's always best to follow standards. Always assume that every user is trying to break your security.